# Reactive form validation but getting error

Tags: angular

I got this error in reactive form validation

Object is possibly 'null'.

8       *ngIf="!registrationForm.get('userName').valid && !registrationForm.get('userName').touched"

Answer (score 2):

Reactive forms aren't strongly typed : it means you can't type your form.
The consequence is Angular can't know for sure there is an existing 'userName' control into your form (so possibly null).

You can solve it by making your control nullable by adding a question mark on both assertions :

```
*ngIf="!registrationForm.get('userName')?.valid && !registrationForm.get('userName')?.touched"
```